# Acessing custom property with AddComponent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity3D I've got a script that adds the variable 'eaten' as a component.

```
using UnityEngine;
[AddComponentMenu("My game/IsEaten")] 
public class IsEaten : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public bool Eaten; 
}
```

Yay! I can then add another script to access 'Eaten'

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Eaten someScript;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        someScript = GetComponent<IsEaten>();
        bool temp = someScript.Eaten;
        print(temp); // false
    }
}
```

Which works fine. What do I have to do to access the variable with dot notation from another script? ie

```
if (myCube.eaten == true)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: what is the type of myCube? Is it a game object or a script instance?

Comment: I don't really get the question here. You've just demonstrated how to access it. Where is the problem?

Comment: #David myCube is a gameObject (a cube)

Comment: #Bart I want to just add one component to the cube to give it a custom property that I can then access globally from any other script with just .eaten property. Which I am sure is possible.

Comment: Well, there are a number of ways I can think off, depending on your exact scenario. Will you only ever have one object that has that exact property? Will many objects have it, but will they all be set to the same value? Will each object have its own and is it acceptable to find the object by name? ... Perhaps enlighten us a bit more about what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I'll elaborate: I'm want to add a custom component to save me time in the long run. There will be a number of objects in the scene, say 20.  Each of the objects will have their own isEaten property (which basically effects their visibility) Depending on what the user does the objects will be switched on or off (or back again!) The objects get affected individually. They can be identified by name.

Answer (score 0):

You know, in Unity one does rarely create the whole script to add a single property to some object. The common approach is to think of scripts as 'components' (which they are, in fact). Let me explain this, a component is a single piece of code that add certain functionality to your `GameObject`, like ability to animate, or to behave the laws of physics. So, maybe, it would be better to reform your `IsEaten` class to form a true component, like `Pickup` (I'm assuming that you need `Eaten` property for the pickup of some sort) that will have functionality to be eaten by a player, or something.

```
// You will actually need to attach a collider (and check the 'IsTrigger' checkbox on it) to your GameObject
// Then this method will be called whenewer some game object with a collider (e. g. player, npc's, monsters) will enter the trigger of this object
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    // Check whether this object was eaten before and if the actor entering our trigger is actually the player
    if (!Eaten && other.tag == "Player")
    {
        // Make shure that we will not get eaten twice
        Eaten = true;
        // Apply some effect to the player that has devoured us
        other.GetComponent<Player>().AddHp(25);
    }
}
```

Other than that, I'm personally thinking, that getting out of your way to simply enable a little sweeter syntax is not worth the hassle, but, if you provide some insight of what are you actually trying to implement, I may try to help you with it :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it might be using Get/Set:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{


    private Eaten someScript;

    // start new!
    public bool eaten
    {

        get
        {
            return someScript.Eaten;
        }

        set
        {
            someScript.Eaten = value;
        }
    }
    // end new!

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        someScript = GetComponent<IsEaten>();
        bool temp = someScript.Eaten;
        print(temp); // false
    }
}
```

Then you can access the Test class property:

```
Test t = GetComponent<Test>();
t.eaten = true;
```

ath.